# JSF Ajax Update not updating the component

Tags: ajax, jsf

Following is the scenario. I have left panel which contains all the menu items. When I click on the menu item the corresponding pages should be loaded in the center / main panel with out page refresh. So I use ajax (setupdate method) to load the page when the menu item is clicked.

My requirement is I have the same page loaded for some set of menu items. But based on the menu item selection I need to retrieve the records from the database hence the page layout remains the same. But I get the same page served for all the menu items. Only for the first time, the call is sent to the backing bean and for subsequent clicks, no call is made to the backing bean and the same page is getting served.

I am using PrimeFaces 3.4.1 and JSF 2.0

Note: I am dynamically loading the screen. In Client page, I use #{menuMB.screenName} to load the screen dynamically.

Following is the code snippet.

### Template page

```
<f:view contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" encoding="UTF-8" >

        <div id="outerWrapper">

            <div id="contentWrapper">
                <div id="leftPanel">
                    <div class="companylogo">

                    </div>
                    <div class="jsmenu">
                        <ui:insert name="leftPanel">
                        </ui:insert>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="mainContentWrapper">
                    <div id="pageHeader">
                        <ui:insert name="pageHeader">
                        </ui:insert>
                    </div>
                    <div id="mainContent">
                        <div id="mainStyle">
                            <ui:insert name="mainContent">
                            </ui:insert>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearFloat"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearFloat"></div>
            <div id="footer">
                <ui:insert name="footer">
                </ui:insert>
            </div>
        </div>
    </f:view>
```

### Client XHTML

All the pages are loaded inside the mainOutputPanel which is inside the mainContentForm. I am getting the screen name that needs to be loaded from the backing bean menuMB.

```
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/pages/protected/templates/layoutTemplate.xhtml">


        <ui:define name="pageHeader">
            <ui:include src="/pages/protected/templates/loginHeader.xhtml">
            </ui:include>
        </ui:define>
        <ui:define name="leftPanel">
            <h:form id="leftMainForm">
                <ui:include src="/pages/protected/templates/requestfactoryleft.xhtml">
                </ui:include>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
        <ui:define name="mainContent" >
            <h:form id="mainContentForm" enctype="multipart/formdata" prependId="true">
                <h:panelGroup id="mainOutputPanel" layout="block" >
                    <ui:include src="#{menuMB.screenName}">
                    </ui:include>
                </h:panelGroup>

            </h:form>

        </ui:define>
        <ui:define name="footer">
            <ui:include src="/pages/protected/templates/footer.xhtml">
            </ui:include>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>

</h:body>
```

### Left XHTML (Contains the menu which is loaded dynamically from the database)

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
            xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com  /jsp/jstl/core">

     <div class="testmenu" style="padding:7px; 
             border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; margin-top: 7px; 
             background: darkgray;  width: 187px;">
        <div id="rfMainMenu">
            <p:panelMenu id="rfleftMainMenu" model="#{menuMB.mnuModel}" >
            </p:panelMenu>
        </div>

     </div>


</ui:composition>
```

### Backing bean (to load the pages dynamically when menu item is selected)

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "menuMB")
public class MenuMB implements Serializable {


    @PostConstruct
    public void loadMenu() {

      if (getLoggedUser() != null) {
          fmList = loginService.getMenuForUser(getLoggedUser());
      }

    //Call createMenu method to populate the sub menu and menu items

     createMenu(fmList);
  }

    public void loadScreensForUser(ActionEvent event) {
        MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem) event.getComponent();
        String attrName;

    try {
        if (menuItem != null) {
            selectedMenuItem = menuItem.getId();

            //Get the screen name from the properties file
            menuUrl = RequestFactoryContextUtil.getResourceBundleString(menuItem.getId());

            //Set the screen name to be displayed
            setScreenName(menuUrl);

            //Call update to update the form  
          RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("mainContentForm:mainOutputPanel");

        }


    } 

    catch (Exception exc) {

    }

  }


  private void createMenu(List<FunctionMaster> fmList) {
    //Submenu rfSubMenu = new Submenu();

    try {
        if (fmList != null) {
            for (FunctionMaster sub : fmList) {
                if (sub.getParentFunctionID() == 0) {
                    Submenu rfSubMenu = new Submenu();
                    rfSubMenu.setLabel(sub.getScreenDisplayName());
                    getMnuModel().addSubmenu(rfSubMenu);

                    for (FunctionMaster item : fmList) {
                        if (item.getParentFunctionID() != 0) {
                            if (item.getParentFunctionID() == sub.getFunctionID()) {

                                MenuItem rfSubItem = new MenuItem();

                                rfSubItem.setId(item.getFunctionName() + item.getFunctionID().toString());
                                rfSubItem.setValue(item.getScreenDisplayName());

                                rfSubItem.setImmediate(true);

                                rfSubItem.setUpdate(":mainContentForm:mainOutputPanel");
                                rfSubItem.setAjax(true);
                                rfSubItem.setRendered(true);
                                rfSubItem.setIcon("search");
                                //rfSubItem.setIcon("ui-icon-search");

                                 ExpressionFactory factory = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
                                 //rfSubItem.setActionExpression(factory.createMethodExpression(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(), #{menuMB.loadScreenFromMenu}", Void.class, new Class[]{ActionEvent.class}));
                                 MethodExpression methodExpr = factory.createMethodExpression(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(), "#{menuMB.loadScreensForUser}", Void.class, new Class[]{ActionEvent.class});
                                 MethodExpressionActionListener actionListener = new MethodExpressionActionListener(methodExpr);
                                 rfSubItem.addActionListener(actionListener);

                                 rfSubMenu.getChildren().add(rfSubItem);
                                //addMenuItem(rfSubItem);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //mnuModel.addSeparator(new Separator());

                }

            }
        }
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        String excep = ex.getMessage();
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Have you made a debug in order to check if the `loadScreensForUser` executed and doesn't give any error?

Comment: Yes I debugged and I did not get any exception. As I said, my backing bean is called only once and for subsequent menu click, I get the same page

Comment: What is a scope of your backing bean?

Comment: How are you triggering the `loadScreensForUser` method? What is the scope of `menuMB`? Please, post the code where you initialize the menu items.

Comment: Most times it's a bad idea to back a page with a SessionScoped bean, for mainly the reasons you're experiencing now : stuff loading or working only the first time(when the session bean or variable inside the session bean is first initialized); Can you try experimenting with a smaller scope for the page backing bean?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I believe I tried with Request scope and did not work. Any way, I will try once again with both Request and View scope as advised. I have also posted the code that creates and initializes the menu dynamically. Please note the method loadScreensForUser is added through methodExpression. I would also like to mention that when the menu item is clicked, the datatable is populated with records from the database. The data table is in a different page and populated using another managed bean.

Comment: As suggested, I tried with both View scope and Request scope and the issue still persists.

Comment: I again tried with RequestScope. Now the data table is updated with the new set of values. It does load the data table on the first click, but only during the second click of the same menu item.

Comment: Sorry, one more update. I changed the MenuMB bean from Session scope to request scope and also the other managed bean (RequestMB) which populates the data table from Session scope to Request. Now the update issue is resolved. But when I click the onToggle in data table the listener in the RequestMB bean is not executed. Earlier, since it was in Session this was working fine. After I changed to Request scope, the listener is not getting fired.

Comment: I have fixed this. Thanks for every one for their valuable time and inputs

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that `<h:body>` resides outside the `<ui:composition` this will cause the `<h:body>` to be dropped.... (anything outside the `<ui:composition` is being ignored)

I suggest you to place the  `<h:body>` tags inside the template itself